# fetch data from urllib2 or request in Python

Tags: python, url, request, urllib2

I have to fetch search result from python.

Suppose following is target url where I am searching `heart` keyword.

```
http://journals.aps.org/search/results?clauses=[{%22operator%22:%22AND%22,%22field%22:%22all%22,%22value%22:%22heart%22}]&sort=relevance
```

But search result by `urllib2` and `request` are not coming.

working on following code:

**By `request`**

```
>>> import requests
>>> url = "http://journals.aps.org/search/results"
>>> payload = {"clauses": [{"operator":"AND","field":"all","value":"heart"}], "sort": "relevance"}
>>> r = requests.get(url, params=payload)
>>> b = r.text
```

**By `urllib2`**

```
>>> import urllib2
>>> search_url ="http://journals.aps.org/search/results?clauses=%5B%7B%22operator%22%3A%22AND%22%2C%22field%22%3A%22all%22%2C%22value%22%3A%22heart%22%7D%5D&sort=relevance"
>>> 
>>> req = urllib2.Request(search_url, headers={'User-Agent' : "Mozilla/5.0"})
>>> f1 = urllib2.urlopen(req)
```

Can not get correct result by above script.

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear from your question where you're stuck, both examples work for me. What is the "correct result" you expect?

```
>>> import requests
>>> url = "http://journals.aps.org/search/results"
>>> payload = {"clauses": [{"operator":"AND","field":"all","value":"heart"}], "sort": "relevance"}
>>> r = requests.get(url, params=payload)
>>> print r.text[:40]
<!DOCTYPE html><!--[if IE 8]><html class
>>>>
```

And:

```
>>> import urllib2
>>> search_url ="http://journals.aps.org/search/results?
>>> clauses=%5B%7B%22operator%22%3A%22AND%22%2C%22field%22%3A%22all%22%2C%22value%22%3A%22heart%22%7D%5D&sort=relevance"
>>> req = urllib2.Request(search_url, headers={'User-Agent' : "Mozilla/5.0"})
>>> f1 = urllib2.urlopen(req)
>>> print f1.read()[:40]
<!DOCTYPE html><!--[if IE 8]><html class
>>>
```

Comment: both examples are working but content return by examples are not same as content which we see on bowers.

Comment: Can you be more specific? What's different between what you're getting back and what you see in the browser?

If there's a difference in the raw HTML, that sounds like something with the site you're accessing, rather than an issue with code suitable for Stack Overflow.

If you're expecting rendered HTML to be returned, then Python is probably the wrong tool for you.